# Request to change position of 'Looking for a job?' dialog

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs, design, site-ads

When I am reading a question, I see this *'Looking for a Job?'* dialog:

See [this video](https://youtu.be/vJXSKMdp-Zs) for more details.

I feel like the *'Related'* dialog should be placed on top of the *'Looking for a Job?'*. Because the *'Related'* dialog is small, and probably would not really hide the *'Looking for a Job?'* dialog fully.

Because when you are reading a question, you would want to know what questions are related to it, so that you get a better view on what is going on, sometimes.

So this is basically what I am expecting:
[image: feature request]

If not the above, then it should just be placed some where else.

I do not think it matters for the *'Hot Network Questions'* dialog, because it is not really needed to be on top.

**I think the best thing to do would be to add an option to change its position.**

Comment: I added the entire block to my uBlock Origin to do that :)

Comment: If there was a meta tag called *'site-layout'* it would be good fit for this question.

Comment: Yes. [uBlock Origin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UBlock_Origin) not to be confused with any other ad blocker with a similar name. I can't remember the name of the block I added to the filter. I've added quite a lot, and even if I disable the extension now, the block only comes on occasion. I see I have a `stackoverflow.com##.js-sidebar-zone` and a `stackoverflow.com###newsletter-ad.mb16.s-sidebarwidget` in there though.

Comment: The "Looking for a Job?" block is an advertisement which is intended to make money for Stack Overflow. The entire point of an advertisement is to get people's eyeballs on it. Just the fact that you're asking for this tends to indicate that the positioning as it is is more effective for the advertisement than the positioning you're requesting. If you want something like this acted upon, then make arguments that are based on business reasons to have it in one location or the other. In other words, make a case that it's overall better for the business to have it in the position you're proposing.

Comment: Note: I don't have any say in where this block is placed. I'm merely trying to emphasize that if you want something, then it's usually a good idea to present arguments which are relevant from the point of view of the people making the decisions.

Comment: I don't think using an ad blocker indicates that you don't support a site. If you don't click the ads in the first place, then there is no difference. After all, revenue is usually calculated by the number of times an ad is clicked.

Comment: @Spectric that's why I click on ads at times to drive a bit of revenue to the owner of the site I'm looking at.

Comment: @RichardChambers I also click on them everytime from when Spectric told me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Being able to access the "Related" dialog is more common than the "Looking for a Job" dialog so it makes sense to make the "Related" dialog more prominent or accessible by swapping them in the column order.

An alternative would be to make the "Looking for a Job" dialog have a minimize control on it so that a person could collapse the dialog or expand it. Rather than showing the list, perhaps a collapsed dialog would show the title bar of "Looking for a Job" along with the first job in the list.

And perhaps make the uppermost dialog in the rightmost column, "The Overflow Blog" and "Featured on Meta" dialog, to also be collapsible.

The collapsed/expanded state would be saved and carried over from session to session.

Comment: @Chi.C.J.RajeevaLochana Thank you. I assume the ad dialog would have to remain as is since it is an ad after all, however the other two in the column are definitely collapse/expand candidates.